# Awk: I want to use the input filename to generate an output file with same name different extension

Tags: awk, filenames

I have a script that looks like this:

```
#! /bin/awk -f

BEGIN { print "start" }
{ print $0 }
END { print "end" }
```

Call the script like this: `./myscript.awk test.txt`

Pretty simple - takes a file and adds "start" to the start and "end" to the end.

Now I want to take the input filename, lets call it `test.txt`, and print the output to a file called `test.out`.

So I tried to print the input filename:

```
BEGIN { print "fname: '" FILENAME "'" }
```

But that printed: `fname: ''` :(

The rest I can figure out I think, I have this following to print to a hard-coded filename:

```
#! /bin/awk -f

BEGIN { print "start" > "test.out" }
{ print $0 >> "test.out" }
END { print "end" >> "test.out" }
```

And that works great.

So the questions are:

1. how do I get the input filename?
2. Assuming somehow I get the input file name in a variable, e.g. FILENAME which contains "test.txt" how would I make another variable, e.g. OUTFILE, which contains "test.out"?

**Note:** I will be doing much more awk processing so please don't suggest to use sed or other languages :))

Comment: save FILENAME in a variable and use `sub` on that variable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#! /bin/awk -f

BEGIN { 
    file = gensub(".txt",".out","g",ARGV[1])
    print "start" > file
}
{ print $0 >> file }
END {
    print "end" >> file
    close(file)
}
```

I'd suggest to `close()` the file too in the `END{}` statement. Good call to Sundeep for pointing out that FILENAME is empty in BEGIN.

Comment: This is really nice and simple for me to understand - thanks v much : )

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 'foo' > ip.txt
$ awk 'NR==1{op=FILENAME; sub(/\.[^.]+$/, ".log", op); print "start" > op}
       {print > op}
       END{print "end" > op}' ip.txt
$ cat ip.log 
start
foo
end
```

Save `FILENAME` to a variable, change the extension using `sub` and then print as required

From [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html)

> Inside a BEGIN rule, the value of FILENAME is "", because there are no input files being processed yet

Comment: A possible workaround to get the value of `FILENAME` in the `BEGIN{}` statement would be to read the value of `ARGV[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and the explanation for FILENAME. I also printed FILENAME within the "body" (if that's the right term) but it did not print there either... : (

Comment: for the sample file I showed in the answer, can you tell what's the output you get for `awk '{print FILENAME}' ip.txt` ?

Comment: @Sundeep ahh...sorry, actually it was a type-o in my part - it does work as you said FILENAME prints correctly in the body thanks : )))

Comment: @Sundeep - btw I like your answer, but I marked Deamon's answer just because I prefer the simple syntax - if I could mark up both I would..

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNU awk (gawk), you can use the patterns `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE`

```
awk 'BEGINFILE{
        outfile=FILENAME; 
        sub(".txt",".out",outfile); 
        print "start" > outfile 
     }
     ENDFILE{
        print "stop" >outfile
     }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

You can then use the variable `outfile` your the main `{...}` loop.
Doing so will allow you to process more that 1 file in a single awk command.